# Can I deploy a smartcontract with web3 1.0, without the metamask popup?

Tags: web3js, metamask

I'm using web3 1.0 to programmatically deploy smartcontracts and make transactions, and metamask to sign those transactions, since i don't want to have hardcoded fragile things.

I would like metamask to stop asking the permissions and do it automatically instead, is this possible?

Comment: I do not think you can sign using metamask private key without a popup. If you want to sign something without a popup you need to manage the keys on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. I am able to use web3 without metamask to send transactions and listen to event.

Comment: so what? the question was how to use metamask without popup.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into EthersJs instead of web3. It's way better for what you're trying to achieve.

> One major difference between ethers.js and web3 is how they handle key
>   management and interaction with the ethereum blockchain. Web3 assumes
>   that there is a local node connected to the application. That node is
>   assumed to store keys, sign transactions, and interact with and read
>   the ethereum blockchain. In reality, this is not often the case — most
>   users are not running geth locally. Metamask effectively emulates that
>   environment through a browser application, and so most web3 apps
>   require Metamask to hold keys, sign transactions, and interact with
>   the ethereum mainnet.
>
> Ethers.js takes a different approach that we believe gives developers
>   more flexibility. Ethers.js separates the “node” into two separate
>   roles:
>
> A “wallet” that holds keys and signs transaction, and
>     A “provider” that serves as an anonymous connection to the ethereum network, checking state and sending transactions
>
> This allows developers to manage these two roles discretely — perhaps
>   using Infura as the provider, and a hardware device for the wallet.